# How convert a genuine UK shapefile(other than the one from natural earth) to d3/topojson?

Tags: topojson, united-kingdom

I am following Mike's page (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) to make UK's map. I've converted Mr. Crone's UK postcode shapefile into topojson but failed to display it correctly.

http://www.sharegeo.ac.uk/handle/10672/51?show=full

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON postcodes.json gb_pca_2010.shp
topojson -o uk.json --id-property Label postcodes.json
```

The resulting json is of 2.2M big. I have used the following code to display it

```
var height, svg, width;
width = 960;
height = 1160;

svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

d3.json("uk.json", function(error, uk) {
  var projection, subunits;
  if (error) {
    return console.error(error);
  }
  subunits = topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.postcodes);
  projection = d3.geo.mercator().translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
  return svg.append("path").datum(subunits).attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(projection));
});
```

The result is that firefox freezes and in the end, I get half black and half white display. :( I have also tried mapshaper to simplify it to 1MB but still not working.

What else I could have tried?

Comment: Have you tried it on other browsers to see if it is a Firefox Issue or generic?

Comment: chrome freezes as well. yes, it is generic.

Comment: I uploaded the shapefile to http://www.mapshaper.org/ and can do visual simplifications. The results from that website cannot be displayed by above script.

Comment: here's the actual converted topojson file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b3ic75aws19q9hx/gb_pca_2010.json

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
var projection = d3.geo.albers().center([ 5.5, 56.4])
  .rotate([4.4, 0]).parallels([50, 60]).scale(1200 * 3);

var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection).pointRadius(2);

var svg = d3.select("div#ukmap").append("div")
  .classed("svg-container",true)
  .append("svg").attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 1000 800")
  .classed("svg-content-responsive", true);

d3.json("/data/uk/uk.json", function(error, uk) {
  var subunits = topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.subunits),
  places = topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.places);

svg.selectAll(".subunit").data(subunits.features)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit " + d.id; })
  .attr("d", path);

svg.append("path")
  .datum(topojson.mesh(uk, uk.objects.subunits, function(a, b) {
    return a !== b && a.id !== "IRL"; 
  })).attr("d", path).attr("class", "subunit-boundary");

svg.append("path")
  .datum(topojson.mesh(uk, uk.objects.subunits, function(a, b) {
    return a === b && a.id === "IRL";
  })).attr("d", path).attr("class", "subunit-boundary IRL");

svg.selectAll(".subunit-label").data(subunits.features)
  .enter().append("text").attr("class", function(d) {
    return "subunit-label " + d.id;
   }).attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; 
   }).attr("dy", ".35em").text(function(d) {
    return d.properties.name;
   });

svg.append("path").datum(places).attr("d", path).attr("class", "place");

svg.selectAll(".place-label").data(places.features)
  .enter().append("text").attr("class", "place-label")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) +  ")";
   }).attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.geometry.coordinates[0] > -1 ? 6 : -6;
   }).attr("dy", ".35em").style("text-anchor", function(d) {
    return d.geometry.coordinates[0] > -1 ? "start" : "end";
   }).text(function(d) {
    return d.properties.name;
   });
});
```